# How do I get distinct COUNT in pivot?

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a following table:

```
State   LAB GROUP   DATE    CODE    ID
UP  A   I   1-Jan   1   345
UP  R   S   1-Feb   1   456
UP  A   S   1-Jan   2   567
DL  R   S   1-Feb   3   678
DL  T   S   1-Jan   1   789
DL  A   S   1-Jan   2   900
MN  T   S   1-Jan   3   1011
MN  R   I   1-Feb   1   1122
MN  S   I   1-Feb   2   1233
```

I need a pivot table of following type:

```
STATE   A   R   T   TOTAL
UP  2   1   0   3
DL  1   1   1   3
MN  0   1   1   2
```

DISTINCT COUNT OF ID FOR EACH LAB FOR EACH STATE.

I then need the pivot tables filtered for following columns:

GROUP
DATE
CODE

So 1st table will have the pivot table above counting only those records which have GROUP=S
2nd table will have the pivot table above counting only those records which have CODE=1

and so on, I wish to put multiple conditions. and generate several tables one by one and export them.

If this is possible in SQL please let me know! I ruled out excel vba due to the size of table (source table will have 800,000 records approx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
Select [State],[A],[R],[T],Total = [A] + [R]+ [T]
from 
(
    Select [State],
           [A] = Sum(Case when LAB='A' then 1 else 0 END) ,
           [R] = Sum(Case when LAB='R' then 1 else 0 END) ,
           [T] = Sum(Case when LAB='T' then 1 else 0 END) 
   from YourTable
   group by [State]
)a
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b915/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #t(States VARCHAR(10),LAB VARCHAR(5),GROUPs VARCHAR(5),DATEs VARCHAR(10),CODE INT,ID INT)
INSERT INTO #t values('UP','A','I','1-Jan',1,345)
INSERT INTO #t values('UP','R','S','1-Feb',1,456)
INSERT INTO #t values('UP','A','S','1-Jan',2,567)
INSERT INTO #t values('DL','R','S','1-Feb',3,678)
INSERT INTO #t values('DL','T','S','1-Jan',1,789)
INSERT INTO #t values('DL','A','S','1-Jan',2,900)
INSERT INTO #t values('MN','T','S','1-Jan',3,1011)
INSERT INTO #t values('MN','R','I','1-Feb',1,1122)
INSERT INTO #t values('MN','S','I','1-Feb',2,1233)



SELECT States,ISNULL(A,0) A,ISNULL(R,0) R,ISNULL(T,0) T,ISNULL(A,0)+ISNULL(R,0)+ISNULL(T,0) total
FROM 
(
    SELECT States,LAB,Count(ID) AS cnt FROM #t GROUP BY States,LAB /*apply GROUP DATE CODE condition here*/ 
) AS PVT
PIVOT(MAX(cnt) FOR LAB IN (A,R,T)) pvt
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using PIVOT :

```html
WITH PivotInUse AS (
 SELECT state,lab,COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY state,lab
  )
SELECT STATE
 ,COALESCE([A], 0) AS A
 ,COALESCE([R], 0) AS R
 ,COALESCE([T], 0) AS T
 ,COALESCE([A], 0) + COALESCE([R], 0) + COALESCE([T], 0) AS TOTAL
FROM PivotInUse
PIVOT(SUM(cnt) FOR lab IN ([A],[R],[T])) AS p;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your sample table

```
SELECT * INTO #TEMP FROM
(               
    SELECT 'UP' [State],'A' LAB,'I' [GROUP],'1-Jan' [DATE],1 CODE,345 ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'UP','R','S','1-Feb',1,456
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'UP','A','S','1-Jan',2,567
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DL','R','S','1-Feb',3,678
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DL','T','S','1-Jan',1,789
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DL','A','S','1-Jan',2,900
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MN','T','S','1-Jan',3,1011
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MN','R','I','1-Feb',1,1122
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'MN','S','I','1-Feb',2,1233  
)TAB
```

Now you need to get the distinct count of each state and get the sum as the result to show `Total`
in pivoted result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [State],LAB,SUM(CNT) CNT 
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    [State],LAB,
    CASE WHEN [State] IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE COUNT([State]) OVER(PARTITION BY [State],LAB) END CNT  
    FROM #TEMP
)TAB
GROUP BY [State],LAB
WITH ROLLUP
```

Now we need to get the distinct columns for pivot(@cols) and columns to identify and replace null with zero in pivot(@NullToZeroCols)

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)
DECLARE @NullToZeroCols NVARCHAR (MAX)


SET @cols = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',['+LAB+']' FROM #NEWTABLE GROUP BY LAB  FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)

SET @NullToZeroCols = SUBSTRING((SELECT DISTINCT ',ISNULL(['+LAB+'],0) AS ['+LAB+']' 
FROM #NEWTABLE GROUP BY LAB FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000)
```

Join the pivotted query with the #NEWTABLE to get the `Total` for each State

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT P.State,' + @NullToZeroCols + ',T2.CNT TOTAL FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT [State],LAB,CNT FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM(CNT)
                 FOR [LAB] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            JOIN #NEWTABLE T2 ON P.[STATE]=T2.[STATE] 
            WHERE P.State IS NOT NULL AND T2.LAB IS NULL AND T2.[STATE] IS NOT NULL;'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

Here is your result

[image]

Here is the SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2588/1 (If it shows any error while loading the page, just click RUNSQL, it will work)

Now if you want to get the result as you said **DISTINCT COUNT OF ID FOR EACH LAB FOR EACH STATE**, just change

```
OVER(PARTITION BY [State],LAB)
```

to

```
OVER(PARTITION BY [State],LAB,Id)
```

which will show the following result after executing the pivot query

[image]